# Replacing Terms with human readable names in Kibana Tables

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have a kibana table that shows terms and counts against them ([Example](https://www.evernote.com/l/ALG6PRae6C5AhrSzHJxPDabGl0JgW5-DjaU)).

How do I apply a separate mapping, that already exists, that maps these ID's onto actual human readable names?

Comment: Fix grammar, make a question.

Answer (score 0):

How about the translate{} filter in logstash?  You can define the values in-line, or have it read from a file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My actual scenario is as follows. I have objects with human names e.g. (ID: 12345, Human Name: "Table Lamp"). Ever so often cataloging would change the Human Name. If the name changes to "Victorian Table Lamp" and if I aggregate over the translate filter, the aggregates would be bifurcated. I want this mapping to be applied post processing / during rendering, because then I would not need to reprocess.
We currently do this via find / replace text browser plugins. I want something that does not involve user interaction.